# Angular components in different directory

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook, compodoc

I am working on storybook and need to include multiple components for  document generation using compodoc but I have found that when writing stories, the component must be in the same directory as the story itself. If I reference a component from a different folder, none of the arguments/documentation is generated.

Is it possible to have components located in a different folder from the story?

Note:I am using angular version 16.1.4, Storybook version 7.3.2

**current folder structure**

```
- Src
  -- Lib
     --- It has multiple component files with documentation (eg:button.component.ts).
  -- Stories
     --- All the storybook files (eg:button.stories.ts).
```

**stories.ts**

```
import { Meta, StoryFn } from '@storybook/angular';

import { AccordionComponent } from './accordion.component';
import { code } from './accordion-example';

export default {
    title: 'Core UI/Accordion/Single Tier Group',
    component: AccordionComponent,
  } as Meta;
  
export const SingleTierGroup: StoryFn = (args) => ({
    props: args,
});

SingleTierGroup.parameters = {
    docs: {
        source: {
            code,
            language: 'jsx',
            type: 'auto',
        },
    },
};
```

**main.ts file**

```
import { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/angular';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
    addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/addon-interactions',
        'storybook-zeplin/register'
    ],
    features: {
        storyStoreV7: true
    },
    framework: {
        name: '@storybook/angular',
        options: {}
    },
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
    docs: {
        autodocs: true
    }
};

export default config;
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "..",
    "paths": {
        "core-ui": ["../src/lib/components"],
        "core-ui/charts": ["../src/lib/charts"],
        "core-ui/mini": ["../src/lib/mini"],
        "core-ui/a11y": ["../src/lib/a11y"],
        "core-ui/data-viz": ["../src/lib/data-viz"],
        "core-ui/illustrations": ["../src/lib/illustrations"],
        "core-ui/logos": ["../src/lib/logos"],
    },
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "../src/lib/**/*",
    "../src/stories/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../automation",
    "../src/docs",
    "../src/schematics",
    "../src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../tools",
  ],
  "files": [
    "./main.ts",
    "./manager.ts",
    "./preview.ts",
    "./themes.ts",
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**preview.ts file**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { applicationConfig, moduleMetadata, Preview } from '@storybook/angular';

import { CoreUIModule } from '../src/lib';
import { StorybookModule } from '../src/stories/storybook.module';
import { backgrounds } from './themes';
import { setCompodocJson } from "@storybook/addon-docs/angular";
import docJson from "../dist-docs/documentation.json";


setCompodocJson(docJson);

const preview: Preview = {
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [StorybookModule]
        }),
        applicationConfig({
            providers: [
                importProvidersFrom(
                    BrowserAnimationsModule,
                    CoreUIModule,
                    HttpClientModule,
                    StorybookModule
                )
            ]
        })
    ],
    parameters: {
        actions: {
            argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*'
        },
        backgrounds,
        controls: {
            expanded: true, // set true to make the controls tab description visible 
            matchers: {
                color: /(background|color)$/i,
                date: /Date$/
            }
        },
        docs: {
            canvas: {
                sourceState: 'shown'
            },
            story: {
                inline: true
            }
        },
        options: {
            storySort: {
                method: 'alphabetical'
            }
        },
        zeplinLink: 'https://app.zeplin.io/project/5efc933d856ca782003a74dd'
    }
};

export default preview;
```

I tried using addDecoratores({}) but it gives error saying component is defined in two modules (app and storybook module)